# Start point in ovalInRect

Tags: ios, swift2, uibezierpath

is there a way to change the starting point from ovalInRect form "right" to "left"?
it seems that no matter how I create it the "starting" point is always on the "right side...

```
 let ovalPath = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: CGRect(x: 515, y: 276.5, width: 280.5, height: 214.5))
        let ovalShapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        ovalShapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor
        ovalShapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor().CGColor
        ovalShapeLayer.lineWidth = 1.5
        ovalShapeLayer.path = ovalPath.CGPath

        self.view.layer.insertSublayer(ovalShapeLayer, atIndex: 1)
```

thanks

Comment: If you use `bezierPathWithArcCenter:radius:startAngle:endAngle:clockwise:`, you can control the start and end, so if you go from `-M_PI` to `M_PI`, it will start on the left. But that's admittedly a circle. If you need oval, starting from left, then you either need to define your own `UIBezierPath`, or use this routine, but transform the view/layer in order to flip it.

Comment: I have tried this but it doesn't do anything... let mirrorXorigin = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(-1.0, 1.0)
        ovalPath.applyTransform(mirrorXorigin)

Comment: shapeLayer does not have applyTransform

Comment: I am sorry. this throws an error... ovalShapeLayer.applyTransform(mirrorXorigin)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Start with a circle of diameter 1 centered at the origin, with the starting angle you want. Then transform that circle into an oval that inscribes your rect.

```
extension UIBezierPath {

    convenience init(ovalInRect rect: CGRect, startAngle: CGFloat, clockwise: Bool) {
        self.init()
        // Create a circle at the origin with diameter 1.
        addArcWithCenter(.zero, radius: 0.5, startAngle: startAngle, endAngle: startAngle + 2 * CGFloat(M_PI), clockwise: clockwise)
        closePath()

        // Construct a transform that moves the circle to inscribe `rect`.
        var transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity
        // This part moves the center of the circle to the center of `rect`.
        transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, rect.midX, rect.midY)
        // This part scales the circle to an oval with the same width and height as `rect`.
        transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, rect.width, rect.height)

        applyTransform(transform)
    }

}
```

Example use:

```
let oval = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: CGRectMake(50, 20, 100, 200), startAngle: CGFloat(-M_PI), clockwise: true)
Swift.print(oval.bounds)
```

Output:

```
(50.0, 20.0, 100.0, 200.0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an update to the answer by *@rob mayoff*, with latest swift version :

```
extension UIBezierPath {
  convenience init(ovalIn rect: CGRect, startAngle: CGFloat, clockwise: Bool) {
      self.init(arcCenter: CGPoint.zero, radius: 0.5, startAngle: startAngle, endAngle: startAngle + 2 * CGFloat(Float.pi), clockwise: clockwise)
      apply(CGAffineTransform(scaleX: rect.width, y: rect.height))
      apply(CGAffineTransform(translationX: rect.midX, y: rect.midY))
  }
}
```